# Ruby on Rails - Simpe_Calendar. Visualizar las semanas de dos en dos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

Como podeís ver en mi captura de pantalla, tengo un problema con la segunda semana. Los días que aparecen son los mismos que los de la semana anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En app/views/calendar/index.html.erb:

```
<%= week_calendar number_of_weeks: 2 do |date| %>
  <%= date %>
<% end %>
```

En app/views/simple_calendar/_week_calendar.html.

```
<div class="simple-calendar">

<!-- Weeks number and arrow for previous and next month-->
<div class="calendar-heading">
  <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.previous', default: 'Previous'), calendar.url_for_previous_view %>
  <% if calendar.number_of_weeks == 1 %>
    <span class="calendar-title">Week <%= calendar.week_number %></span>
  <%else%>
      <span class="calendar-title">Weeks <%= calendar.week_number %> and <%= calendar.end_week %></span>
  <%end%>
      <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.next', default: 'Next'), calendar.url_for_next_view %>
</div>
<br>

<!-- Only one week in this line. Week numbers are shown in the first column of the table -->
<!-- <div class="calendar-heading">
  <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.previous', default: 'Previous'), calendar.url_for_previous_view %>
    <span class="calendar-title">Weeks</span>
  <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.next', default: 'Next'), calendar.url_for_next_view %>
</div> -->

<%= date_range.slice(0, 7) %> <br>
<%= date_range.slice(7, 14) %> <br>
<%= date_range.class %>

<!-- Table headers -->
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <% date_range.each_slice(7) do |week| %>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <% date_range.slice(0, 7).each do |day| %>
                <th><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %>
                  <%-# Date relative to the day -%>
                    <%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
                </th>
              <% end %>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tr>
        <!-- <td rowspan="2">Week <%= calendar.week_number %></td> -->
        <td>Morning</td>
          <% week.each do |day| %>
            <%-# Buttons -%>
              <%= content_tag :td, class: calendar.td_classes_for(day) do %>
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                  <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary">INDISPO</button>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
                </span>
              <% end %>
            <%-# End of block -%>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Evening</td>
          <% week.each do |day| %>
            <%-# Buttons -%>
              <%= content_tag :td, class: calendar.td_classes_for(day) do %>
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                  <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary">INDISPO</button>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
                </span>
              <% end %>
            <%-# End of block -%>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Mi problema se encuentra en el thead...
No consigo hacer que pase en la segunda parte de la cadena de "date", el date_range.slice(7, 14).

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error no está en que estés o no usando un helper, está en que para el header usas el mismo `date_range.slice(0, 7)` independiente de en qué iteración estés, cuando deberías estar usando `week`. En la práctica, en vez de:

```
          <% date_range.slice(0, 7).each do |day| %>
            <th><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %>
              <%-# Date relative to the day -%>
                <%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
            </th>
          <% end %>
```

debería ser:

```
          <% week.each do |day| %>
            <th><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %>
              <%-# Date relative to the day -%>
                <%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
            </th>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: Pues funcionó... asi de fácil! Te lo agradezco muchisimo!
No puedo darte un voto positivo por tener menos de 15 puntos de reputación, pero de nuevo, gracias!!!

Comment: una cosa que no me quedó muy clara, es la parte esta:

`<%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %>
                <%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, [])`

Me funciona bien, pero me gustaría tener otro formato, el mismo que da en la cadena de week, vease Mon, 15 May 2017.

Comment: Supongo que `<%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %> ` debe estar sacando los Mon, Tue, etc.. desde `config/locales` y `<%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>` debe estar trayendo el resto de la fecha, aunque desconozco que hace efectivamente esa última línea sin más código como referencia. De todas formas si la variable `day` es de tipo `Date` o derivados de ésta, puedes usar [`.strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) para darle formato.